# Live search not works with datatable

Tags: php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap live search inside the dataTable

Live search select box is only visible in first page. After the first page its not visible.

I have downloaded the required JS / CSS files into my pc

```
<script src='./js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script src='./js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='./js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='./js/bootstrap-select.min.js'></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.jobreq_list').DataTable();
} );
</script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='./css/bootstrap.min.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='./css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
```

[image]

[image]

**HTML**

```
  echo"<table class='jobreq_list table table-striped table-bordered'>
    <thead><tr><th>S.no</th><th>Supervisor</th><th>JobReq</th><th>Planning Date</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    $sno=0;
    foreach($result as $row ) {
    $supervisor=$row['supervisor'];
    $ufirstname=$row['firstname'];
    $ulastname=$row['lastname'];
    $uid=$row['uid'];
    $rat_planning_date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row['rat_planning_date']));
    $sno++;
    echo"<tr><td>$sno</td><td>$supervisor</td><td>$ufirstname</td><td>
    <select class='selectpicker' data-show-subtext='true' data-live-search='true'>
           <option>Expert PHP</option>
            <option>Demo PHP</option>
            <option>PHP Tutorials</option>
            <option>PHP Framework & PHP Framework PHP FrameworkPHP Framework</option>
            <option>PHP Libraries</option>
            <option>HTML</option>
            <option>CSS</option>
            <option>JS</option>
            <option>MySQL</option>
          </select>

    </td></tr>";
    }
    echo"</tbody></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of Live Search, you should use their rerender method when you change the page in you datatable. I am not 100% sure, but my guess is that Live Search is only fired on visible items on the page at any given moment. From the Live Search documentation:

> You can force a re-render of the bootstrap-select ui with the render
>   method. This is useful if you programatically change any underlying
>   values that affect the layout of the element.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
```

[Read the Live Search methods documentation here](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/)

Now, all you got to do is find the equalent event for DataTables that you can hook onto when the page is changed.